# Help with Test Class for on insert Opportunity trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

A user can create an Opportunity only by converting a Lead. But for some reason the primary contact on the opportunity is not getting populated. I have created an Opportunity trigger that runs on insert and adds the primary contact using ConvertedOpportunityId and ConvertedContactId on lead.

Here is the trigger code -

```java
trigger FixPrimaryContact on Opportunity (after insert) {   
    for(Opportunity newuser : Trigger.new){
        if(newuser.Lead_ID__c != ''){  
            List<Lead> leads= [Select Id, ConvertedContactId from Lead where ConvertedOpportunityId = :newuser.Id];          
            for (Lead l: leads) {             
                List<Opportunity> updopps = [select id from Opportunity where id = :newuser.id];
                for(Opportunity single_opp :updopps){
                    single_opp.Primary_Contact__c = l.ConvertedContactId;
                    update single_opp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a test class that just creates an Opp but I am getting code coverage error.

Here is the test class code -

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public class TestFixPrimaryContact {
    
    static testMethod void insertNewOpp() {
       Opportunity oppToCreate = new Opportunity();
   
       oppToCreate.StageName = 'Rapport Building';
       oppToCreate.Lead_ID__c = '00QQi000002B8sMMAS';
       oppToCreate.CloseDate = System.Today();
       oppToCreate.Business_Unit__c = 'xyz';
       
       oppToCreate.Probability_of_Funding__c = '50% - Budget approved';
       oppToCreate.Probability_of_PO_to_JH__c = '50% - Budget approved';
       oppToCreate.LeadSource = 'Website';
       oppToCreate.Name = 'TriggerOpp12345';
       oppToCreate.AccountID = '0016000000IHP8DAAX';
       oppToCreate.Primary_Contact__c = '0036Q00002w9yXyQAI';

       insert oppToCreate;
    }
}
```

The trigger is working in the sandbox instance but I am facing code coverage issue while moving the trigger to production. Can you please guide me with this issue?

Comment: Some general notes: 1) Using `seeAllData=true` is bad practice. You should be creating the data required for the test in the test class itself. 2) Hard-coding Ids is a recipe for disaster. Whatever Id you specify, it _will not be the same in other orgs_ (excepting special cases between a production org and a full or partial copy sandbox). 3) The `testMethod` keyword is deprecated. You should use the `@isTest` annotation for test methods instead.

Comment: Also, as with your previous question, you have queries inside of a loop (and one inside of a nested loop, along with DML). It's hard to say if it's more important to fix your test first, or fix the issues in the trigger being tested. At any rate, queries and DML inside of a loop is about as close to a mortal sin as we can get in Salesforce. Your test itself is also not making any assertions. Assertions are the most important part of testing. You can get coverage for a method that returns `5` when you tell it `add 2 and 2 together`. It's the assertions that would tell you the code is incorrect.

Comment: Note that the Opportunity is related to its _primary_ contact automatically via the OpportunityContactRole junction record - you could just query that rather than rely on ConvertedContactId

Answer (score 0):

in test class, for Lead_ID__c, AccountID, Primary_Contact__c create a record above the   Opportunity  and assign value to the field like this

Test class:

```
Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'one';
        insert acc;

 oppToCreate.AccountID = acc.Id;
```

and in trigger
change the condition

```
if(newuser.Lead_ID__c != null)
```